# Safe javascript characters to use as key value pairs in list Id attribute

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a treeview (using the dyna tree version) and I have extended the JS to include multiple context menus.

Originally I was using

```
<li id="@ID@:3.@TYPE@:3">
```

to hold details I may need and converted this to JSON, like so:

```
//Gets the ID value
var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(span).toString()
node = node.replace(/|/g, '\"')
node = node.replace(".", ',')
node = jQuery.parseJSON('{' + node + '}');
```

this was fine but unfortunately this was to be used in a razor MVC view, so @ was out. i diodnt want @@ so thought a | may be a better seperator

```
<li id="|ID|:3.|TYPE|:3">
```

But chnaging JS to

```
var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(span).toString()
node = node.replace(/|/g, '\"')
node = node.replace(".", ',')
node = jQuery.parseJSON('{' + node + '}');
```

gives me an error when parsing the JSON. Is there any advice on what is wrong and what characters I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex should have been `/\|/g`, because `|` is a special character in regex. Anyway, this is pretty horrible way to do it, you can just have the json directly in an element:

```
<span id="hello" data-json='{"ID":3, "TYPE": 3}'></span>
```

jQuery even automatically parses the json for you, when you use `.data()`:

```
$("#hello").data("json").TYPE; //3
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jJQ7z/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using these kinds of values for the id. The id is supposed to be a simple nominative identifier for a given object on a page, used above all to get the object for JavaScript calls. It is good practice to only give IDs to elements on the page that need them, as it prevents you from using up good id names on elements which won't make use of them.

If you need to include supplementary data in a tag, you can create custom tags which begin with `data-`. You can put whatever information you would like in as many of these kinds of tags that you would like and it remains perfectly valid HTML. For example:

```
<li data-myId="3" data-type="3">
```

You can then retrieve these values in your JavaScript as you would any other attribute value.